# Debezium SqlServerConnector timezone issue with AvroConverter

Tags: apache-kafka, timezone, avro, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am creating a Debezium connector to retrieve data from a SQL Server table.
In that table, there is a `START_DATE` column (the type is *datetime*) that is representing a datetime in local timezone (Euroep/Rome).

The problem is that the connector interpret that as a UTC datetime and convert the column values to timestamps. When I convert back the timestamps to datetime, the datetimes are obviously referring to UTC timezone.

I tried putting `"database.serverTimezone": "Europe/Rome"` as an option in the connector configuration, but it does not work.

```json
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "config": {
    "name": "xxx",
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    ...
    "database.serverTimezone": "Europe/Rome"
  }
}
```

Comment: Avro isn't the issue here... I assume you mean UTC. But what datatype is the Avro schema using? There is a [converter](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/timestampconverter.html) but you will want to use ExtractNewState Debezium transform as well. But, basically, it's the Java database driver that controls what timezones get used by the client, not the serialization framework.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer for your answer. Yes, I was obviously meaning UTC time, sorry for the typo. I cannot use the converter because it assumes the value be referring to the Epoch timestamp, while it refers to the "local timestamp" (for example, if in my database there is the value 2022-12-12T01:00:00, the Source connector should transform it to 1670803200, while it is transformed to 1670806800 ignoring the database timezone)

Comment: Okay, well, as the [docs say](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html) , several types like `DATE` "_does not include timezone information_", and "_Such columns are converted into an equivalent Kafka Connect value based on UTC_"... Meanwhile, `database.serverTimezone` is not a listed property... Perhaps you need to add `DATETIMEOFFSET` field to the database?

Comment: That could be a possibility. Nevertheless, the lack of database time zone management through Apache Kafka is quite annoying. Thank you @OneCricketeer for your time.

Comment: Kafka itself has nothing to do with databases. I suggest reaching out to Debezium JIRA or their Google Group to get more targeted response